# pycharm ctrl pageup/pagedown to tab between open files

Tags: pycharm

i am trying to use ctrl+pageup or ctrl+pagedown to jump between open files in pycharm.

I'm trying to do this in pycharm - no dice. This *might* be because i switched to "eclipse keys". Any ideas how i convince pycharm to let me do this? Currently it does nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open **Settings | Keymap** section, create a copy of the selected keymap (if it is a pre-defined one) and reassign 'Select Next Tab' and 'Select Previous Tab' actions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sheezy. thanks! The ctrl+pageup/down was tied to "move carat to top/bottom" Thankfully, pycharm let me remove the extant actions automatically.